# Обратотка одной строки запроса PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть запрос, который возвращает одну строчку из базы.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT user_id, password FROM users WHERE user_id = ?';
 $base = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Как получить значение строк `$row['user_id']` и `$row['password']` после выполнения запроса.

Вот если много строк в результате запроса, то:

```
foreach ($base as $row)
{
  echo $row['user_id'] . "\n";
  echo $row['password'];
}
```

Подскажите, как обработать одну строку?

Comment: обрабатывается точно также.

Comment: `foreach()` работает даже с пустым массивом, так что обработать можно точно также.

Comment: Что лучше использовать цикл или не использовать цикл и в запрос добавить LIMIT 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться методом [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php). Код с его использованием может выглядеть, например, так:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($id));

$data = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo($data['user_id'] . ': ' $data['password']);
```